# xml document parser with ajax error

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I have an ajax call with datatype is xml and in only IE it is showing 'Type mismatch' error and it works fine in FF.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: term,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(response) {
            //response= {"popup":{"errorFlag":"false","terms":"understanding","description":"Description of understanding"}};

            // Create the xml document from the responseText string.
            if( window.DOMParser ) {
                var xmlDoc = response;
            } else { // Internet Explorer
                xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async="false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(response); 
            }
```

})

Comment: (a) If you set `dataType` to `xml`, jQuery will already parse the XML for you, you don't have to do it manually. (b) Your response is not XML but **JSON**. No XML parser can understand that.

Comment: you are missing the closing bracket of the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)?.

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: term,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        //response= {"popup":{"errorFlag":"false","terms":"understanding","description":"Description of understanding"}};
        // now access all elements regardless of the browser
        var flag = response.popup.errorFlag;
        var terms = response.popup.terms;
        var description = response.popup.description;
    }
});
```

As Felix have already noted, your response is [JSON: The Fat-Free Alternative to XML](http://www.json.org/fatfree.html).

Comment: Even simpler: Change the `dataType` to `json` and jQuery will parse it automatically.